# What can I do when receiving 'Access denied for user' error message in phpMyAdmin in cPanel?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

When I select phpMyAdmin in cPanel, the following error message appears:

`mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'name'@'localhost' (using password: YES).`

Answer (score 0):

Session timeout issue?

This may not be the answer to your particular setup, over here the cPanel Tools page was refreshed in the Chrome browser, after which there appeared a "**HTTP error 401 Invalid Security Token**" error.

Logging back in and launching phpMyAdmin did not get that issue any more.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to find out whether this is a PHPMyAdmin or a MySQL issue.

Let's open a server terminal or ssh to the server with the appropriate user and run

```
mysql -u yourusername -p
```

the terminal will ask for your password. Provide it. If the login succeeded, then your user credentials are correct in terms of connecting. In this case proceed to test the operation you wanted to execute via PHPMyAdmin. If it succeeds, then it's a PHPMyAdmin issue. Maybe your session expired. Or you encountered a bug or bad credentials. The point is that in this scenario it's definitely PHPMyAdmin.

If in the terminal you encounter the same problem, then it might be due to lacking privilege or incorrect credentials. If so, contact your server admin and ask him to grant your user proper access from the appropriate host (localhost in this case). Or to reset your password.